# SqlDateTime overflow error in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms-1.7

I am unable to figure out why i am getting this error even i am selecting the proper date values. I also want when user click to create course, dates should be filled automatically.

"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM"

$

````
#CoursePart.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Aspects;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Utilities;

namespace Orchard.Club.Models
{
public class CoursePart : ContentPart<CoursePartRecord>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return Record.Description; }
        set { Record.Description = value; }
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return Record.Location; }
        set { Record.Location = value; }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return Record.Category; }
        set { Record.Category = value; }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return Record.StartDate; }
        set { Record.StartDate = value; }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return Record.EndDate; }
        set { Record.EndDate = value; }
    }

    public double Fees
    {
        get { return Record.Fees; }
        set { Record.Fees = value; }
    }
}

public class CoursePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string Category { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual double Fees { get; set; }
}
}
```
#Course.cshtml
 ```
@model Orchard.Club.Models.CoursePart

@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;   

@{
Script.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js");
Script.Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js");
}      

<fieldset>     
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Location)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Location)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Location)
</div>


<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Category)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Category)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Category)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @*@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.StartDate))*@
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartDate)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EndDate)
    @*@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.EndDate))*@
</div>


<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Fees)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Fees)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Fees)
</div>
````

````
@( Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true))

@( Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group
                .Add("telerik.common.min.css")
                .Add("telerik.metro.min.css"))
)

```
#Create.cshtml
```
@{ Layout.Title = T("Create User").ToString(); }

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) { 
@Html.ValidationSummary() 
// Model is a Shape, calling Display() so that it is rendered using the most specific    template for its Shape type
@Display(Model)    
} 

```
#Controller Snippet
```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {                     
        var course = _orchardService.ContentManager.New<CoursePart>("Course");
        dynamic model = _orchardService.ContentManager.BuildEditor(course);            
        return View((object)model);                                         
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreatePOST()
    {            
        var Course = _contentManager.New("Course");            
        var userPart = Course.As<CoursePart>();            
        userPart.StartDate = _clock.UtcNow;
        userPart.EndDate = _clock.UtcNow;
        // Store the new user into the database
        _orchardService.ContentManager.Create(Course);

        dynamic model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(Course, this);

        _contentManager.Publish(Course);

        _orchardService.Notifier.Information(new LocalizedString("Course has been created."));                                        

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
 ```
````

**PartDriver.cs**

```
  namespace Orchard.Club.Drivers
  {
  public class CourserPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<CoursePart> {

    protected override DriverResult Display(
        CoursePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Course",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Course(
                Name: part.Name,
                Description: part.Description));
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CoursePart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Course_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/Course",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CoursePart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
      }
    }
   }
```

**CoursePartHandler.cs**

```
    namespace Orchard.Club.Handlers
    {
    public class CoursePartHandler : ContentHandler
    {        
    public class CustomerPartHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        public CustomerPartHandler(IRepository<CoursePartRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
            Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<CoursePart>("Course"));

            OnInitializing<CoursePart>(AssignDates);

            OnLoaded<CoursePart>(SetDates);
        }

        private void SetDates(LoadContentContext context, CoursePart part)
        {
            var obj = context.ContentItem.As<CoursePart>();
            obj.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            obj.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

            part.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            part.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        protected void AssignDates(InitializingContentContext context, CoursePart part)
        {
            var obj = context.ContentItem.As<CoursePart>();
            obj.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            obj.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

            part.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            part.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
      }
     }
     }
```

## Course.cshtml

```
@model Orchard.Club.Models.CoursePart

<fieldset>     
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Location)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Location)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Location)
</div>


<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Category)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Category)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Category)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate)</div>
<div class="editor-field">        
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartDate)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EndDate)    
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndDate)
</div>


<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Fees)</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Fees)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Fees)
</div>  
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What about setting **breakpoints**?

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by setting the datetime column nullable in my model. I don't know if it is appropriate in your case though.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
    var contentItem = _contentManager.New("Course");
    _contentManager.Create(contentItem, VersionOptions.Draft);
    dynamic model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(contentItem, this);
    _contentManager.Publish(contentItem);
```

The `.Create()` call generates INSERT statements for `contentItem`.  Then, additional changes made to the item will generate UPDATE statements.

At the point in time `.Create()` is called, you still have zeros in your `DateTime` fields of your object.  This is why SQL Server Compact is unable to create your item.  You need to fill in default values before this point.

Comment: Please see my original post, i have changed the code. I am getting time correctly to StartDate  and EndDate variables but still it giving me error.

Comment: Ok if this problem cant be solved, i can change the model to make StartDate as string to store in database but problem here is how can i display in View to select date?e.g. datepicker if field is string